# onchange event handler triggering twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have written the below jQuery functions to invoke filters on a datatable. But the "change" jQuery function seems to seems to invoke two times  for a single click , hence, if i try to turn off  one of the filter, it will immediately turn itself back on.

Function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        rowReorder: {
            selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
        },
        responsive: true,

        initComplete: function () {
            var filters = $('div[id$=referalFilters]').find('input:checkbox');
            filters.each(function () {
                dict.push({
                    key: $(this).prop('name'),
                    value: $(this).prop('checked')
                });
                $(this).change(function () {
                    var currentName = $(this).prop('name');

                    for (var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
                        if (dict[i].key == currentName) {
                            if (dict[i].value == true) {
                                dict[i].value = false;
                            } else {
                                dict[i].value = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
                        if (dict[i].value == true) {
                            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                                var currentStatus = data[3];
                                var found = false;
                                for (var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
                                    if (currentStatus == String(dict[i].key)) {
                                        if (dict[i].value == true) {
                                            found = true;
                                        }
                                    } 
                                }
                                if (found) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                                return false;
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    table.draw();
                });
            });
            //this.api().columns().every( function () {
            //    var column = this;
            //} );
        }

    });
});
```

I will appreciate, if someone could let me know what triggers the change function multiple times.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a81h11tc/ . In Js fiffle, the button seems to toggle but, the filtering does not happen.

Comment: Multiple elements sharing the same `id`?

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle for us or make this into a snippet with the proper HTML to accompany it?

Comment: @AngelosChalaris : will do that now

Comment: @MelanciaUK : not sharing same ID

Comment: Whoever has given a negative point, should atleast tell why have you given

Comment: @LibinJoseph I do believe it might be due to the fact that the code you provided is not enough to reproduce the problem, however the question is well formed and it is clear what you are asking as far as I can tell. Please, whoever downvoted the post, explain why you did so!

Comment: @AngelosChalaris :  Yes, the whole point of stackoverflow is ask for help, when you do not know things. And i am sure I have taken the effort to explain the question. If the information that I have given is not sufficient , please ask. Anyways, thanks for the support  :)

Comment: @AngelosChalaris : I have added the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your problem was an undefined variable, `dict` inside `initComplete`. After I added `var dict = [];` before `var filters = ...`, it worked like a charm. (My understanding is that you wanted the column *Status* to hide the rows that contain the value of the clicked filter. If you want the opposite, modify your code accordingly.) Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a81h11tc/4/) of the altered code, it should work the way you wanted.

**TIP:** By the way, remember to always check the browser's console as in most cases you can see the proper error messages for stuff like this (i.e. for your code it said `RefereceError: dict is not defined`, which was basically the only problem your code had).

Comment: In my case the error ended being the bootsrap. js being called twice